# Data from Select List not Posting in Form

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I have a textinput with datalist. The data is coming from database. I select the Product and click Add Product button. The data is added in the select list with size 10 successfully. The code for the select list is.

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm" action="productDetails.php">
        <b>Select a Product:</b>
        <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" size="10" style="width:500px">
        </select>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Show Details">    
</form>
```

[Screenshot of datalist and select list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7EcP.jpg)

When i click submit the form post to another page productDetails.php. Where i am trying to get the items in the select list but it shows NO ITEM or $_POST['mySelect'] to be empty. What am i doing wrong?

```
if(empty($_POST['mySelect'])||!isset($_POST['mySelect'])){
    echo "no item";
    }else{
    $productsList = $_POST['mySelect'];
    echo $productsList; 
}
```

Please let me know where am i doing wrong. Appreciate it.

Comment: //First check the connection to the database values:
 `$query=$conn->query("select * from tablename");
 $result=$query->fetch_assoc();
 echo $result['mySelect'];`

Comment: mate the database is connecting perfectly and brining the values. the issue is the values are not coming from form to here.

Comment: Are your `options` being added via JavaScript? Because the `<select>` node is empty.

Comment: yes by javascript.